# Does SELECT REPLACE() overwrite the records in the db

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to select a column from a db with all occurrences of a character replaced by another.

I looked at [SELECT REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) but I'm afraid of using it.

Comment: The answer would be NO, it does not affect the data in the database.

Comment: Of course not. You have to `UPDATE` to alter a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, getting values in a `select` statement does not change the values in the table.

The `replace` will be applied to the data after reading it from the table, and before the result is returned from the query.

Note: The exception from this rule would be if you have a trigger on the table that changes the data when it is selected. Then it's the trigger that changes the data, and using a function like `replace` on the values still has nothing to do with how the trigger changes it.

Comment: Does MySQL really support triggers on `select`?

Comment: I like the principal stated by Guffa.  The default answer is no, a replace (Or any other function) will not affect the data in a DB.  But take note on where the resultant data set is being used.  If this feeds into an update, this update will be affected.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't know exactly, but I thought that I should mention that possibility, even if it only applies to some databases.